# count(expr) returns a count of '1' on a table with an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

Tags: mysql

I want to return a count of the number of non-NULL values in the rows retrieved by a SELECT statement in my query below. I noticed that when i execute the query on a table with an empty result set, $stmt->num_rows returns a value of 1.

My full code is shown below:

```
// initialize statement
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
// prepare SQL query
$sql = 'SELECT
        COUNT(vault_id) AS rows
      FROM 
        vault 
      WHERE 
        resource = ?';
if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) 
{
// bind the query parameter
$stmt->bind_param('s', $sanitizedpage);
// execute the query, and store the result
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
}
// Return a count of the number of non-NULL values in the rows retrieved by a SELECT   statement.//
if ($stmt->num_rows == 1)
{
   echo $stmt->num_rows;
}
```

So the num_rows() method in the SELECT query statement above returns the value (1) when executed against an empty table.

If it helps, find below my table structure :

```
`vault_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`resource` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`vault_id`)
```

I need your advice to resolve this.

Comment: Well yes the result has 1 row with a count, (presumably of 0) in it. You need to get the row and the read the value off it. Your approach would work if you selected all the rows and used num_rows, but that as you've rightly decided would be a silly approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TO answer this consider the following table in mysql

```
mysql> select * from test ;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

So there is no data in this table.

Now lets run the following command

```
mysql> select count(*) from test ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So its returning 1 row with the count(*) value as 0

So this is exactly same happening , meaning when you run count(*) the value may be 0 but it will always return one row unless you have used group by

Answer (score 0):

@Abnik is correct, however if you want to keep your app logic and adjust the query so it works, use this query instead:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM vault 
    WHERE resource = ?';
```

This will return no rows for a "not found" condition, and 'n' rows for "found".

If the number of matching rows is small when resource is found, this would give adequate performance (though not as good as count).

Comment: adding a GROUP BY clause to my query as recommended by Abhik produced the needed output. because i am  interested in the number of rows, not the number
of values, the COUNT(expr) function remains a better performance option.